# Which class should be responsible for serialization?

Tags: c++, oop, serialization, class-design

I have a very general question about what is a better approach and why: make an object responsible for serializing itself or have a separate `Reader` and `Writer` classes to do this?

---

Here is an illustration. I have a file format which consists of a header and a series of objects.

### Example #1 - embedded serialization

```
class Header
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Header& header);
    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, Header& header);
}

class Object
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Object& object);
    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, Object& object);
}

class Reader
{
    void readHeader(Header& header) { ifs_ << header; }
    void readObject(Object& object) { ifs_ << object; }

private:
    ifstream ifs_;
}

class Writer
{
    void writeHeader(Header const& header) { header >> ofs_ }
    void writeObject(Object const& object) { object >> ofs_ }

private:
    ofstream ofs_;
}
```

In this case all serialization details go into the overloaded `<<` and `>>` operators.

### Example #2 - external serialization

```
class Header
{

}

class Object
{

}

class Reader
{
    void readHeader(Header& header) { // serialization details go here }
    void readObject(Object& object) { // serialization details go here }

private:
    ifstream ifs_;
}

class Writer
{
    void writeHeader(Header const& header) { // serialization details go here }
    void writeObject(Object const& object) { // serialization details go here }

private:
    ofstream ofs_;
}
```

Note: I provide `<<` and `>>` operators just as an example, it doesn't mean I necessarily want to store data as text. This methods could be as well replaced by `serialize`/`deserialize` methods which use binary format.

Comment: Reader/Writer would have to be friends with every class?

Comment: It depends, but I see your point. Here's an example where they aren't:
http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/laslib.zip

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: IMHO, a Reader class specialization for each one of your entity classes would be a better solution.

Long answer:

Probably serialization shouldn't be a concern of your entities (i.e.: Header), thus this functionality shouldn't belong to them (see [single responsability principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) in Wikipedia).

On the other hand an external serializer that knows all about the entity classes is an inadmissible tight coupling in your system (readability and maintainability would be severely affected in the future).

So, my suggestions is creating Readers/Writers generalizations that know only how to serialize/deserialize a specific entity class (i.e.: HeaderReader/HeaderWriter).

[]'s,